# While printing ArrayList multipe value it displays only -> '[]'

Tags: java, arraylist, command-line

I have a problem with displaying the elements of the `ArrayList` in Java. While returning the `ArrayList` when its called from the Views to BMIAnalyzier class which contains the dummy values form now. It shows
[]
[]
 When java files are run.

1. Views.java

   ```
   Switch(choice[0]){
       case 1:

           //Option 1 to display the data fo subject of given subject id.

           ArrayList<Records> arraylist = analyzier.find(choice[1]);

           System.out.println(ArrayList);
           Break;
       Case 2:
           //Option 2 to display the data fo subject from the range given of BMI.

           ArrayList<Records> arraylistList = analyzier.find(Double.parseDouble(choice[1]),Double.parseDouble(choice[2]));

           for (int i = 0; i < arraylistList.size(); i++){

               System.out.println((arraylistList.get(i)).toString());
           }

           Break;

       default:
           System.out.println("wrong input");
   }
   ```
2. BMIAnalyzier.java

   ```
   public class BMIAnalyzier {

       public Records find(String sid) {

           System.out.println(new Records(sid, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "none"));

           return new Records(sid, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "none");
       }

       public ArrayList<Records> find(double bmi1, double bmi2) {

           ArrayList<Records> alr = new ArrayList<>();

           alr.add(new Records("S01", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "none"));

           alr.add(new Records("S02", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "none"));

           return alr;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Records.java

   ```
   public class Records extends ArrayList<Records> {
       private String SubjectId;
       private Double height;
       private Double width;
       private Double bmianalyzier;
       private String categories;
       public ArrayList <Records> list =new ArrayList<>();
       public Records(String sid, Double h, Double w, Double bmi, String c) {
       }
       //getter ans setter methods.
   }
   ```

Output:

[image: here I enter the option 2 and range 0 100 and result is in the picture below but that what I wanted to display the values which are in the ArrayList.to see the result of mine click this .]

Comment: come on, if you can not be bothered to format your code and make your question readable, why do you think that we can be bothered to answer/help you?

Comment: Obviously it's empty.

Comment: how are your Break and Switch command working .. I wonder ??

Answer (score 0):

The main mystery is that you have the `Records` class extend `ArrayList`.  I have no idea why you are doing that, but in so, you are inheriting `ArrayList`'s `toString()` method, which is what renders the `[]`, since the array is empty.  You need to implement `toString()` for the `Records` class.

```
String toString() {
    return subjectId + " " + height + " " + width + " " + bmianalyzier + " " + categories;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are new to java. You need to understand the basics first. For instance in your case, ArrayList is a collection which you use to hold multiple values of the same type. With your Records class you are extending the collection which is not required here.

> public class Records extends ArrayList < Records > {

should be

> public class Records {

Also, you should always provide content to your class Constructor otherwise no values would be set for the object.

```
    public Records(String sid, Double h, Double w, Double bmi, String c) {
        this.SubjectId = sid;
       // set other values as well
    }
```

And, find(String sid) is returning Records object

```
ArrayList < Records > arraylist = analyzier.find(choice[1]);
```

should be changed to

```
Records record = analyzier.find(choice[1]);
```

For printing the values of your Records object do as @Niklas suggested